# Написание исламских сакральных терминов

Tags: орфография

В последнее время наши мусульмане, начиная практиковать свою религию, начали употреблять исламские сакральные термины - "АльхамдулиЛьлях" (хвала Аллаху), "АстахфируЛлах" (да простит Аллах), "СюбханаЛлах" (слава Аллаху) и т.д.

Вы обратили внимание, как я написал букву "эль" в некоторых случаях? Совершенно верно, вопреки всем традициям правописания с заглавной буквы, хотя сама буква находилась в середине слова. Поясняю почему: есть правила чтения арабских текстов - таджвид. Там свои специфические правила, согласно которым, когда соединяются два слова, то при этом, как правило, "съедается" буква(вы). Например, мало кто из вас, наверно, знает, что всем известное приветствие "ассаламу алейкум!" (Мир вам) пишется "Аль саламу алейкум".

И вот, исходя из этих правил, многие пришли к выводу, что первую букву "эль" надо писать с заглавной. Потому что, например, "ин+ша+Аллах" (если на то будет воля Аллаха), где, при соединении двух слов "ша" и "Аллах" съедается буква "а" - первая "а" из слова "Аллах", но не "а" из слова "ша". А потому после этого первой буквой в слове "Аллах" становится первый "эль". Если при подобных случаях на арабском какие-либо вопросы даже не напрашиваются в связи с тем, что у них отсутствуют заглавные буквы (всё у них пишется строчными буквами, как и во многих языках), то вот правописание русского языка предусматривают в обязательном порядке писать с заглавной буквы имя собственное.

И вот тут-то возникае дилемма: с одной стороны, правила правописания русского языка, согласно которым имя собственное необходимо писать с заглавной буквы, а с другой стороны - те же правила не предусматривают (если не сказать запрещают) употребление больших букв в середине слова. Если по-русски в имени собственном первую букву надо писать обязательно с заглавной, то при "съеденной" первой букве в слове "Аллах" первой буквой, как уже говорил выше, становится первый "эль", то, соответственно, напрашивается вывод. Поэтому многие, в том числе и ваш покорный слуга, пришли к выводу, что правильней писать "ин шаЛлах", "бисмиЛьлях", (именем Аллаха), "джазакаЛлаху (джазакиЛьляху - для женщины) хайрон" (да преумножит Аллах твои благие деяния).

А как думаете вы, какие будут мнения по этому вопросу, уважаемые филологи?

Answer (score 3):

При переводах со всех языков на русский этот вопрос решается без сохранения заглавной буквы в середине слова - либо разделением на слова, либо заменой буквы на строчную (напр. ирландские фамилии). Пример из религиозных текстов: "аллилуйя" (в переводах трактуется как "восхваляйте Господа").

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший ответ. Думаю есть резон в этих словах.